# Calculating the cumulative ttl (Time to live) for a series of requests

Tags: javascript

I have a series of requests and asked to calculate a the cumulative ttl of the series and given these requests .

```
let requests = [
{requestId: 't2',  startedAt: 1489744808, ttl: 8},
{requestId: 't3',  startedAt: 1489744803, ttl: 3},
{requestId: 't1', startedAt: 1489744806, ttl: 12}, 
{requestId: 't4',  startedAt: 1489744810, ttl: 1}
]
```

What is the algorithm to solve this? as I know that the answer should be 15 in the end.

I would assume that the earliest request `1489744803` should have the largest ttl but that's not the case, instead the `1489744806` request has the largest here so why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve by the following way:

```
let requests = [
   {requestId: 'poiax',  startedAt: 1489744808, ttl: 8},
   {requestId: 'kdfhd',  startedAt: 1489744803, ttl: 3},
   {requestId: 'uqwyet', startedAt: 1489744806, ttl: 12}, 
   {requestId: 'qewaz',  startedAt: 1489744810, ttl: 1}
]

let cumulativeTtl = 15

// Ans:

var max = result = 0;
var min = requests[0].startedAt;

requests.forEach(function(row){
    max = ((row.startedAt + row.ttl) > max) ? (row.startedAt + row.ttl) : max;
    min = (row.startedAt < min) ? row.startedAt : min;    
});
result = (max - min);

console.log((result == cumulativeTtl) ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let minStart = requests.reduce((v, obj) => Math.min(v, obj.startedAt), Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
let result = requests.reduce((r, obj) => Math.max(r, obj.startedAt - minStart + obj.ttl), 0)
```

or

```
let minMax = requests.reduce((o, obj) => { return { min: Math.min(o.min, obj.startedAt), max: Math.max(o.max, obj.startedAt + obj.ttl)}}, { min: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, max: 0 })
console.log(minMax.max - minMax.min)
```

(solution 2 looks a bit more ugly, but needs only one loop over the array.)

Answer (score 0):

first we need to find min and max every request using startedAt and ttl, once you get end min, max then we need to subtract max - min, finally we get the solution.

```
function cumulativeTtl(requests){
    var min = requests[0].startedAt, max = 0;
    for(var i in requests){
        min = (requests[i].startedAt < min)?requests[i].startedAt:min;
        max = ((requests[i].startedAt + requests[i].ttl) > max)?(requests[i].startedAt + requests[i].ttl):max;
    }
    return max - min;
};
```

**explanation:**

```
when i = 0;

min = 1489744808 // (1489744808 < 1489744808)?1489744808:1489744808; 
max = 1489744816 // ((1489744808 + 8) > 0)?(1489744808 + 8):0;

when i = 1;

min = 1489744803 // (1489744803 < 1489744808)?1489744803:1489744808;
max = 1489744816 // ((1489744803 + 3) > 1489744816)?(1489744803 + 3):1489744816;

when i = 2;

min = 1489744803 // (1489744806 < 1489744803)?1489744806:1489744803;
max = 1489744818 // ((1489744806 + 12) > 1489744816)?(1489744806 + 12):1489744816;

when i = 3;

min = 1489744803 // (1489744810 < 1489744803)?1489744810:1489744803;
max = 1489744818 // ((1489744810 + 1) > 1489744818)?(1489744810 + 1):1489744818;
```

finally max-min then we get solution, that's it.

```
max-min = 15 // 1489744818 - 1489744803
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer , can you explain to me the algorithm a bit more . I'm new to the concept of Ttl so a bit more explanation would be great ! Thanks :)

Comment: see the explanation above @stringRay2014

Comment: again if you have any doubt let me know @stringRay2014.

Comment: `for(var i in requests){         min = (requests[i].startedAt < min)?requests[i].startedAt:min;         max = ((requests[i].startedAt + requests[i].ttl) > max)?(requests[i].startedAt + requests[i].ttl):max;     }` wouldn't i in this case be a request rather then a counter ?

Comment: where i is here json index like 0,1,2,3 if your json contain 4 set of key, values.@stringRay2014

Comment: do you have any other doubts @stringRay2014